# Print help when positional arguments not provided

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to execute my Python program. It uses one positional argument. When the positional argument is not provided I want to print help. But all I get is

```
error : too few arguments
```

Here is the Python code :

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description = '''My Script ''')
parser.add_argument('I', type=str, help='Provide the release log file')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I'm expecting the following output when no positional arguments are specified:

```
usage: script.py [-h] I

My Script

positional arguments:
  I           Provide the release log file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Any thoughts how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` doesn't work that way.  You need to ask for help with the `-h` argment.  Otherwise it just gives the `usage` along with the error message.

```
0015:~/mypy$ python3 stack41671660.py 
usage: stack41671660.py [-h] I
stack41671660.py: error: the following arguments are required: I
0015:~/mypy$ python stack41671660.py 
usage: stack41671660.py [-h] I
stack41671660.py: error: too few arguments
0015:~/mypy$ python stack41671660.py -h
usage: stack41671660.py [-h] I

My Script

positional arguments:
  I           Provide the release log file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

You could make the positional argument 'optional' with `nargs='?'`, and add a test for the default value:

```
print(args)
if args.I is None:
    parser.print_help()
```

sample runs:

```
0016:~/mypy$ python stack41671660.py 
Namespace(I=None)
usage: stack41671660.py [-h] [I]

My Script

positional arguments:
  I           Provide the release log file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
0019:~/mypy$ python stack41671660.py 2323
Namespace(I='2323')
```

Another option is to customize the `parser.error` method, so that it does `print_help` instead of `print_usage`.  That will affect all parsing errors, not just this missing positional.

```
def error(self, message):
    """error(message: string)

    Prints a usage message incorporating the message to stderr and
    exits.

    If you override this in a subclass, it should not return -- it
    should either exit or raise an exception.
    """
    # self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
    self.print_help(_sys.stderr)
    args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
```

`